# Count the days of the user creation

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, time

I wonder if is it possible to make a counter that counts how long a user created in mysql has been created? Should I add a new column that stores the date of the creation and substract the value from the today's date? Or should I make it with JavaScript with a localStorage counter? But I think LocalStorage is not the best option to make this because it resets if I want to login from another device and see the value of the dates.

Comment: Storing a timestamp seems like a sensible approach

Comment: `Should I add a new column that stores the date of the creation and substract the value from the today's date` yes that's a pretty standard approach. `Or should I make it with JavaScript with a localStorage counter?` ...that doesn't make a lot of sense because a) it can be easily erased, b) people often log in from more than one device / browser. You've pretty much already explained in your question why that's a bad idea. So I think you know what you need to do.